# Filterrific, Initialising multiple models in controller for one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, filterrific

I am chuffed with the flexibility that comes with Filterrific.

But I am wondering, how one would handle the filtering of multiple ActiveRecord models in one view.

Is there a way to add multiple Models to the filterrific instance variable when initialising in the controller?

So instead of passing one model class as in the sample code below, adding additional model classes.

```
@filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
  Student, #add another set of parameters for a second model somewhere here
  params[:filterrific],
  select_options: {
    sorted_by: Student.options_for_sorted_by,
    with_country_id: Country.options_for_select
  },
  persistence_id: 'shared_key',
  default_filter_params: {},
  available_filters: [],
) or return
```

If it is not possible to add multiple models, is there another way one would handle a scenario where filtering based on multiple models is required? Maybe additionally initialising filterrific in a seperate instance variable?

Thank you!

Comment: I've been having the same issue. I haven't been able to get filterrific to work properly. I use separate instance variables as well. The way I get around it is to create remote forms with custom routes and actions